# What is this Stack Overflow green icon?

Tags: discussion, user-experience

I'm seeing what seems like a new color scheme for the Stack Overflow icon:

[image]

This appears in the *Inbox* and *Hot Questions* items, but not on the list of SE sites, for example.

I see the new icon is used as `<div class="favicon favicon-stackoverflow site-icon grid--cell" title="Stack Overflow">`, and the CSS points to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=08c43b9ad64c, with `background-position: 0 -5958px`.

The usual icon has exactly the same code: `<div class="favicon favicon-stackoverflow site-icon grid--cell" title="Stack Overflow">` and the CSS points to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=08c43b9ad64c, with `background-position: 0 -5958px;`.

However, they look different:

[image]

What's up with this coloring?

Comment: [Non-repro](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/icon-48.png), what's your image's URL?

Comment: I added some info to the question.

Comment: The HTML and CSS you list for the "new icon" and "former icon" are identical. Graphical rendering issue on your machine?

Comment: I see they are identical, but I've never seen such a selective graphical rendering issue. I'll double-check as soon as I can restart my session. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had similar problem with a  icon I made in the past. It's caused by wrong image rendering

Comment: I like how your stackoverflow icon has the colors of coral and the meta icon then has the color of dead coral.

Comment: `Mold Overflow`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

AFAICT, this is a Chrome bug – I've been having the same problem on Chrome Beta (M68) for a while.

Comment: Typical Chrome... move fast and break things.

Comment: How dare they break things in beta! Live as well?

Comment: https://crbug.com/867813 - fixed in 69.

Comment: For context: M69 is scheduled for release one month from today, on the 4th September.

Comment: The fix has been backported to M68 – I can't work out what branch it's actually been merged into, but it should roll out Soon™.

Comment: I'm seeing this on the live version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build, 64-bit, over ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: @E.P. Should be fixed once the new M70 release rolls out, or in M71.